# gitpython creating zip archive

Tags: python, git, gitpython

How can I create an archive with gitpython, I tried the following which creates the file but I can't open it **it tells me an error occurred reading archive the archive appears to be invalid or damaged**

```
from git import *
repo = Repo(repo_path)
assert repo.bare == False
repo.archive(open("repo.tar",'w'))
```

I would like to create a zip file so then I tried this but here it creates an empty zip file (the path to repo is correct as when I use repo.clone it propery clones everything)

```
repo.archive(open("repo.zip",'w'), format="zip")
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to open your file as binary (adding `b` to the `mode` parameter) and close it when you finish. The following modifications to your example make it work correctly:

```
from git import Repo

repo = Repo(repo_path)
assert not repo.bare
with open('repo.zip', 'wb') as archive_file:
    repo.archive(archive_file, format='zip')
```